# Sustainsys.SAML2 uses http-redirect instead of http-post

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I should say that I've just started exploring SAML authentication and bumped into authentication problem which unfortunately I cannot reproduce on my development machine which confuses me even more.

I have the following configuration using OWIN:

```
var options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
{
    Notifications = new Saml2Notifications
    {
        AuthenticationRequestCreated = (request, provider, dictionary) =>
        {
            request.Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpPost;
        }
    },
    AuthenticationType = services.AuthenticationType,
    Caption = services.Caption,
    SPOptions = new SPOptions
    {
        EntityId = new EntityId(Path.Combine(services.RelyingPartyUri, "Saml2"))
    }
};

options.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(services.IdentityProviderConfiguration.IdentityProviderMetadataUri), options.SPOptions)
{
    AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
    Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpPost,
    LoadMetadata = true,
    SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri(services.IdentityProviderConfiguration.SingleSignOnUri)
});

app.UseSaml2Authentication(options);
```

`services` variable contains configuration such as metadata uri, sso uri, etc.

This configuration works perfectly on my machine. I've inspected login SAML request and here is what I have there:

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="id10c4b76119b64952857d38c7581ca0b4" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2018-12-04T14:29:00Z" 
    Destination="https://identity.provider/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/application" 
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://application/Saml2/Acs">
    <saml2:Issuer>https://application/Saml2</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

The authentication then works fine.

When I deploy this code to external server for testing purpose some times it works as expected but quite often I cannot authenticate user because instead of http-post the authentication mechanism uses http-redirect.

In this case I see the following login SAML request:

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="id10c4b76119b64952857d38c7581ca0b4" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2018-12-04T14:29:00Z" 
    Destination="https://identity.provider/trust/saml2/http-redirect/sso/application" 
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://application/Saml2/Acs">
    <saml2:Issuer>https://application/Saml2</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

The difference in the SSO uri which is used for authentication.

What I did so far is checked configuration files to eliminate configuration issue. All configurations are valid and `services.IdentityProviderConfiguration.SingleSignOnUri` contains valid SSO uri with http-post. I've played around with different settings and as you may see in the code snippet I set Binding to HttpPost which I thought should have solved my issue in case if `SingleSignOnServiceUrl` is taken automatically from IDP metadata. I also looked through sustainsys.SAML2 source code and couldn't find anything which could give me a clue.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `LoadMetadata=true` the settings found in the Metadata will override your manual configuration. Obviously the metadata of the Idp contains an endpoint `https://identity.provider/trust/saml2/http-redirect/sso/application` with a POST binding.

To fix this ask the Idp to get their metadata correct. Or set `LoadMetadata=false` and rely on in-code configuration. You must add the Idp signing certificate to your code in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anders! I've checked metadata file. Yes, it contains wrong endpoints. A guy who manages Idp confirmed that. I've set up sustainsys.saml2 to load metadata from file (they provided me one) which solved my issue. I still do not understand one thing, why on my machine manual configuration for `SingleSignOnServiceUrl` is taken into account while on the development server it falls back to metadata from server.